# Get grouped data from DataSource without serverGrouping

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Is it possible to get the grouped data out of a DataSource as if it was server-side grouped?

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [{
        name: "John Doe",
        gender: "male",
        age: 33
    }],
    group:[{
        field: "gender"
    }]
});

ds.data(); // Returns an array of models if you are client-side grouping but an array of grouped models if you are server-side grouping
```

I want the last line (or an alternative method) to return grouped data just like it would with `serverGrouping` set to true (and a remote binding). Is this possible?

Comment: You can just retrieve grouped data and use it as per normal. How do you want to use the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [view method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-view) of the dataSource which returns the dataItems with the corresponding grouping, paging, filtering etc. applied.

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [{
      name: "John Doe",
      gender: "male",
      age: 33
  }],
  group:[{
      field: "gender"
  }]
});

ds.fetch(function(){
  var view = ds.view();
});
```

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thank you.